# nwjs crash Cloud management controller initialization aborted as CBCM is not enabled

Tags: node-webkit, nwjs

I've installed latest binaries on Ubuntu 22.04 from official website http://nwjs.io.nw.js.
Both **nw** from **nwjs** and **nwjs-sdk-v0.79.0-linux-x64** does the same issue.
After starting crashes with this error message.

How can I solve this crash issue?

```
node -v
v20.5.1
```

**nw**

```
[10030:10030:0820/145510.926389:ERROR:chrome_browser_cloud_management_controller.cc(163)] Cloud management controller initialization aborted as CBCM is not enabled.
[0820/145510.952062:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found
[0820/145515.006433:WARNING:process_reader_linux.cc(144)] no stack mapping
[0820/145515.006991:WARNING:process_reader_linux.cc(144)] no stack mapping
Received signal 11 <unknown> 199660001048
#0 0x7fb936660ee3 (/home/bkb/programok/node/nwjs-sdk-v0.79.0-linux-x64/lib/libnw.so+0x6860ee2)
#1 0x7fb936672341 (/home/bkb/programok/node/nwjs-sdk-v0.79.0-linux-x64/lib/libnw.so+0x6872340)
#2 0x7fb92fa42520 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x4251f)
#3 0x7fb936784ebf (/home/bkb/programok/node/nwjs-sdk-v0.79.0-linux-x64/lib/libnw.so+0x6984ebe)
#4 0x7fb93677ddc5 (/home/bkb/programok/node/nwjs-sdk-v0.79.0-linux-x64/lib/libnw.so+0x697ddc4)
#5 0x7fb936674d38 (/home/bkb/programok/node/nwjs-sdk-v0.79.0-linux-x64/lib/libnw.so+0x6874d37)
#6 0x7fb93279fc82 (/home/bkb/programok/node/nwjs-sdk-v0.79.0-linux-x64/lib/libnw.so+0x299fc81)
#7 0x7fb9349b146f (/home/bkb/programok/node/nwjs-sdk-v0.79.0-linux-x64/lib/libnw.so+0x4bb146e)
#8 0x7fb93585dec3 (/home/bkb/programok/node/nwjs-sdk-v0.79.0-linux-x64/lib/libnw.so+0x5a5dec2)
#9 0x7fb935864685 (/home/bkb/programok/node/nwjs-sdk-v0.79.0-linux-x64/lib/libnw.so+0x5a64684)
#10 0x7fb93584356a (/home/bkb/programok/node/nwjs-sdk-v0.79.0-linux-x64/lib/libnw.so+0x5a43569)
#11 0x7fb932d4d021 (/home/bkb/programok/node/nwjs-sdk-v0.79.0-linux-x64/lib/libnw.so+0x2f4d020)
#12 0x7fb93660d384 (/home/bkb/programok/node/nwjs-sdk-v0.79.0-linux-x64/lib/libnw.so+0x680d383)
#13 0x7fb936625163 (/home/bkb/programok/node/nwjs-sdk-v0.79.0-linux-x64/lib/libnw.so+0x6825162)
#14 0x7fb936624bd9 (/home/bkb/programok/node/nwjs-sdk-v0.79.0-linux-x64/lib/libnw.so+0x6824bd8)
#15 0x7fb936625635 (/home/bkb/programok/node/nwjs-sdk-v0.79.0-linux-x64/lib/libnw.so+0x6825634)
#16 0x7fb9365ca509 (/home/bkb/programok/node/nwjs-sdk-v0.79.0-linux-x64/lib/libnw.so+0x67ca508)
#17 0x7fb936625994 (/home/bkb/programok/node/nwjs-sdk-v0.79.0-linux-x64/lib/libnw.so+0x6825993)
#18 0x7fb9365edd3e (/home/bkb/programok/node/nwjs-sdk-v0.79.0-linux-x64/lib/libnw.so+0x67edd3d)
#19 0x7fb93bfd5600 (/home/bkb/programok/node/nwjs-sdk-v0.79.0-linux-x64/lib/libnw.so+0xc1d55ff)
#20 0x7fb935acb773 (/home/bkb/programok/node/nwjs-sdk-v0.79.0-linux-x64/lib/libnw.so+0x5ccb772)
#21 0x7fb935accb2e (/home/bkb/programok/node/nwjs-sdk-v0.79.0-linux-x64/lib/libnw.so+0x5cccb2d)
#22 0x7fb935aca1e6 (/home/bkb/programok/node/nwjs-sdk-v0.79.0-linux-x64/lib/libnw.so+0x5cca1e5)
#23 0x7fb935aca4e2 (/home/bkb/programok/node/nwjs-sdk-v0.79.0-linux-x64/lib/libnw.so+0x5cca4e1)
#24 0x7fb9321d22ca ChromeMain
#25 0x7fb92fa29d90 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29d8f)
  r8: 0000000000000001  r9: 0000000000000001 r10: 0000389800601100 r11: 0000000000000000
 r12: 0000199660001040 r13: 0000000000000000 r14: 0000199660001040 r15: 0000000000000000
  di: 00007fb93cd4a0b0  si: 00007ffebf271638  bp: 00007ffebf271ca0  bx: 00007fb93cd4a0b0
  dx: 0000000010600002  ax: 0000000010600002  cx: 0000199660008020  sp: 00007ffebf271c70
  ip: 00007fb936780610 efl: 0000000000010246 cgf: 002b000000000033 erf: 0000000000000027
 trp: 000000000000000e msk: 0000000000000000 cr2: 0000199660001048
[end of stack trace]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was reported to developers [as an issue](https://github.com/nwjs) and it was answered as completed:

> This is fixed in git and will be available in the next nightly build.

Here is the [link](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/8106)

Answer (score 2):

Try following these steps and see if it works.

1. Install a Node version manager (either of these will work)

   - Win/Lin/OSX - https://volta.sh
   - Lin/OSX - https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm
2. Check what version of Node.js is built in to the version of NW.js you want to use:

   - https://nwjs.io/versions.json
3. Use the Node Version Manager to install and use the matching version
4. Run `node -v` and `npm -v` to verify you are on the matching version

   - For example, if you use NW.js 0.79.0 then you'll want Node 20.5.0
5. Create a new `package.json` file like so:

   ```json
   {
     "name": "test-app",
     "main": "index.html",
     "scripts": {
       "start": "nw ."
     },
     "devDependencies": {
       "nw": "0.79.0-sdk
     }
   }
   ```
6. Then create an `index.html` file:

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
     <head>
       <title>Test</title>
     </head>
     <body>
       <h1>Hello World</h1>
       <script>
         console.log(nw);
         nw.Window.get().showDevTools();
       </script>
     </body>
   </html>
   ```
7. Run `npm install` (will take a moment to download NW.js)
8. Finally run `npm start`

These steps should work on any OS and produce a "hello world" NW.js project. If you are still getting the exact same error, you could try adding this into your `package.json`:

```json
  "chromium-args": "--disable-extensions"
```

If you are getting new errors, update your post.

Comment: Thank you, it solved the problem. It starts with npm start, but when I packed It crashes.

Comment: `node -v`  
`v18.17.1`  
`npm -v`  
`9.6.7`  

`zip -r ../${PWD##*/}.nw *`  

`cat `which nw` '/home/workspaces/electron/nwjs_test.nw'  > app && chmod +x app`  

when I start the app it crashes with error output:

'[17654:17654:0821/154326.936057:ERROR:chrome_browser_cloud_management_controller.cc(163)] Cloud management controller initialization aborted as CBCM is not enabled.
[0821/154326.956681:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found
[17687:17692:0821/154332.045906:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(623)] No net_fetcher for performing AIA chasing.
  `